# Best approach for managing files for offload

Tags: android, service, file-transfer

I have a Service that is woken up by an AlarmReceiver every x minutes looks for files in /some/path/ and if it finds them attempts to offload them to some Cloud based API endpoint.

I'm trying to figure out what the most elegant solution is to avoiding concurrent Alarms from invoking the Service on successive tries and attempting to offload the same files again (if the previous run failed to handle the full offload in the time allotted between Alarms.

I've tried various approaches including keeping track of which files have been marked for upload (in SharedPreferences and sqlLt) as well as simply testing for the existence of a running Service and not starting another in the AlarmReceiver but this all feels kind of hacky.

I'm wondering if I'm overlooking some "correct" way to handle this sort of operation.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to stop polling the file system. You can use a [FileObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to be notified when something interesting happened in your specified directory: https://gist.github.com/shirou/659180

To upload files, I'd suggest a [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) that can be scheduled and retried as needed: http://toastdroid.com/2015/02/21/how-to-use-androids-job-scheduler/

That should get you to an event driven, reliable upload design. This is relativity simple and I would probably just stick to that.

But let's try to batch jobs as much as possible as your question suggested:

Let's assume that you have an upload pending for a file (waiting for network to become available), and get another file created notification. You could at that point grab the [JobInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#getPendingJob(int)) for that job, [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#cancel(int)) the job, and [reschedule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo)) it with the new list of files.

Just my two cents.